# PHP code for removing Unwanted parameters of Youtube URL

Tags: laravel

PHP code for removing Unwanted parameters of Youtube URL

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: If you take the title of your question and remove "Youtube " from it and search for it on google, you should be able to find something that guides you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be:

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?...&...';

$cleanedUrl = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "&"));
```

Comment: It only accept first parameter, if you have `watch?t=123&v=gshsj_jsgs` then it will ignore the `v` parameter and accept `t` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nijo_JU1M&t=299s&ab_channel=MusicHous";
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $query['v'];
print_r($url);
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nijo_JU1M
```

Above code tested [here](https://rextester.com/PSRI83449)